# GoogleMaps for iOS infoWindow to segue with data from entity

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I followed the Code School tutorial on Google Maps for iOS and was able to take a fetched array (from `NSManagedObject`) and assign marker title, snippet and userData and return an `NSSet` of markers that I displayed on the map.

Now I want to show a detail view of the array object when the marker infoWindow gets tapped. I'm an iOS beginner and I don't know how to get back to the object from the infoWindow.

It states in the docs that infoWindows on Goggle maps are just images and can't have buttons or interactive parts so I don't know how to index the infoWindow.

I found an answer to the issue here where a transparent button is attached, the `didTapInfoWindowOfMarker` method is overridden and other delegate methods are employed to move the button around.

Good solution for that problem but I'd like to solve mine by using the helper code already written into the sdk (i.e. I want to use the `didTapInfoWindowOfMarker` method).

Can someone explain how to do this?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MarkerDetail"]) 
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController =   segue.destinationViewController;
        LocationDetailsViewController *controller = (LocationDetailsViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        //Code to turn the marker back into a Location object 

        //and fill in the detailViewController
        controller.locationToView =location;
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MarkerDetail" sender:marker];

}
```

Success!I found a lovely way to achieve exactly what I wanted.Here is my solution.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailNavC"];

NSString *markerCategory=[marker.userData objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *markerName=[marker.userData objectAtIndex:1];
UIImage *markerImage=[marker.userData objectAtIndex:2];

CLPlacemark *markerPlacemark=[marker.userData objectAtIndex:3];
InfoViewController *ivc = (InfoViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

ivc.category=markerCategory;
ivc.name=markerName;
ivc.image=markerImage;
ivc.placemark=markerPlacemark;

[self presentViewController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: I think the closest I've gotten to the result I want is setting up a segue to my destinationViewController then calling the segue in the didTapInfoWindowOfMarker method. I will post an edit that includes the code for both.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the marker and add it to the map, set its `userData` property to an object which contains the info you need.

Then in `didTapInfoWindowOfMarker` cast the `marker.userData` back to that type, and pass the data on to the destination view.

Comment: Ok, this advice got me somewhere. I created an array object for marker.userData, filled it with name,address,image,text then in didTapInfoWindowOfMarker instantiated a detailsViewController and set it's labels and image view to the appropriate objectAtIndex value. I logged output to make sure it was passing the data. So far so good.

Comment: The segue I am trying to use is still not passing any data. In my storyboard it looks like it is originating in the map view, not any particular marker or from the array object. I'll try presentViewController:detailsViewController next and see how that goes. Can you mix nibs and storyboards?